# Tcpdump on AVD Manager Android Emluator

Tags: android, tcpdump, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to capture packets from browser on android emulator (AVD Manager). I'm running android emulator from command line with this command:

```
"Android SDK Emulator path" -tcpdump "tcpdump path" -avd Pixel_XL_API_24
```

and it's showing this warning

> emulator: WARNING: The -tcpdump flag is not supported in QEMU2 yet and
>   will be ignored.

Tcpdump isn't running so I can't capture packets. I've tried to run tcpdump on few android versions, but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution: it's needed to add "-engine classic" to launch command.